# Server midnight - high memory allocations and does not let go, what to check?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, java, apache-2.4

How can I check what my server was doing at midnight, to locate the high memory spike, which he is still holding on.

Only things I'm running on the server is Apache2 with a Flask app, and a Tomcat7 server for some Java services, both are doing nothing.

Is there any system logs or something that can tell me whats going on?

New relic server stats:

[image: New relic server stats]

Glances stats:

[image: Glances stats]

Comment: If the spike stays for more than a minute, isn't it a good idea to write a small script to check the output of `top -c` and `ps` every minute and feed it to a file that you can check in the morning? That way you can see what was loading the server during the midnight-spike.

Answer (score 3):

You have [New Relic](http://newrelic.com) monitoring. You *literally* have a monitoring solution that can tell you what your server is doing with 1-minute granularity!

- Select the relevant timeline in the **Overview** graph.
- Click on **Processes**.
- Sort the processes by RAM utilization.
- Select the process you're concerned about to drill down for more detail.
- *Profit*.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually look at your Cron jobs, as Cron is what usually triggers processes systematically at specified times. Ubuntu is a fairly complex server distro compared to some other minimal linux server distributions. My guess would be some type of job that automatically searches for security updates. so look for any apt-get processes at 12AM daily. As far as the memory usage goes, are you sure it isn't cached? After running updates on my Debian systems, which are very similar to Ubuntu, there is usually a lot of left over memory usage from disk caching. This is perfectly fine, linux will just keep the memory for disk caching until another application requests that memory. It's not actually being consumed, just allocated for caching.